# nginx redirecting for no reason?

Tags: nginx, troubleshooting

This was really annoying and now i see when it happens. If `<ip>/NAME` exist in /var/www (`/var/www/NAME`) nginx will give me a redirect to `www._.com/NAME/` (note the slash and lack of url) which is annoying and just wrong. If the url ends with a `/` it will check the index and serve index.html

How do i either make it give me an error page or add a `/` to the end of it?

```
server {

    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4
    listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

    server_name  _;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;
    root   /var/www;

    location / {
        root   /var/www;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    location /doc {
        root   /usr/share;
        autoindex on;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        deny all;
    }

    location /images {
        root   /usr/share;
        autoindex on;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there any `include` directive in your main configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

[server_name_in_redirect](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#server_name_in_redirect) off; will tell nginx to use the request's Host: header instead of the first server_name argument when generating redirects.